# How do I open a folder within the Code::Blocks IDE?

Tags: c++, windows, ide, codeblocks, text-editor

Is there any way to open a folder in the Code::Blocks IDE without creating a whole new Code::Blocks project itself?

What I mean by opening a folder is:

In VSCode:

[image: vscode screenshot]

I can click on **File** and then click on **Open Folder...** and it will list all the files in that folder in the explorers shown below:

[image: vscode screenshot]

So, is there any way to do this on Code::Blocks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually Codeblocks does not manage projects with folders. You need to add the files manually.
Refer to this http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=21702.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeBlocks doesn't have this command. You can only add files contained in a certain directory and its subdirectories to a project using the command `Project -> Add files recursively`
[image]